# How to split attribute field of a view in ArcGIS Enterprise Portal

Tags: arcgis-portal, sql-view

I am working with a view in ArcGIS Enterprise Portal.  This view contains combined information about the same asset, for example, pipelines.  Some of the information has been combined into a single attribute field, separated by a pipe [ | ].  An example would be pipe diameter: "48 | 54" (for a reducer).

My question is how to split this attribute field by the pipe, for searching and filtering purposes.  I am unable to perform a field calculate on a view. It doesn't necessarily need to be split into separate fields, however if that is the only way, that would be helpful to know.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change how this view is published?  If so, an option could be to add fields at the database level (assuming the data is coming from an enterprise database), and using field calculator, FME, or Data Interoperability Extension to reassign the values in the original column to new Inlet Diameter and Outlet Diameter columns.  What pipeline data model are you using, and how do you intend the user to search for these values in Portal?

Comment: The attributes are stored separately in a postgres database.  GIS houses the geometry, globalid, and diameter in inches (for pipeline). They are joined together using the globalid field. The view can be changed, however the hope was to be able to combine like attributes into a single field and search through them.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to use Regex (Regular Expressions) to accomplish a query.  https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/how-regex-works-in-sql/  Since you're using pipe characters in the field, and Postgres uses pipe characters to split up Regex queries, it looks like you'll need to negate the pipe character as ^| so it doesn't confuse it as a split between Regex query options, as suggested in the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015999/postgresql-9-substring-with-regex-to-get-string-between-string-and-pipe